# Ubuntu 18.04 Wi-Fi won't authenticate

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, iwlwifi, pci

Using Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Vostro.  Wi-Fi has been working fine for several months, including on release 18.xx.  Suddenly it will not connect to my Wi-Fi network that it has been connecting to for months. The Wi-Fi network has good signal, but Ubuntu never finishes the connection authentication.
Rebooted to Windows 10, Wi-Fi connects with no problem.  Installed a USB Wi-Fi dongle, rebooted to Ubuntu, Wi-Fi connection through USB works fine.

Therefore, it seems that the Ubuntu driver for the built-in Wi-Fi device has changed or is corrupted.

Is there a way to force Ubuntu to select the right driver, or how can the driver be replaced?  Following is "`lshw`" portion for built-in Wi-Fi:

```
*-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak]
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: wlp1s0
                version: 34
                serial: 4c:eb:42:35:e0:a3
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-43-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:33 memory:d1600000-d1601fff
```

Thanks for any suggestions/answers.

Comment: Hi MelJ and welcome to askUbuntu! Please format your post according to https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code. You can format your terminal output like code (insert 4 spaces at the beginning of each line or select the code with the mouse and type ctrl+k ).

Comment: Could you add the output of `nmcli con down $connection_name && nmcli --verbose con up $SSID`, where `$SSID` has/is the name of your Wi-Fi (`nmcli device wifi`)?

Answer (score -1):

You should try bypassing NetworkManager. Give this a try. If it works, try reinstalling/configuring that. This is just a workaround so you can get internet if you need to uninstall/update some packages or do maitmence to get your system running smoothly again.

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
wpa_passphrase ssid password > network.conf
sudo wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -iwlp1s0 -cnetwork.conf &
sudo dhcpcd wlp1s0 &
ifconfig
ping google.com
```

If you don't have wpa_passphrase on your machine, network.conf looks like:

```
network={
  ssid=""      # your network's SSID/name
  password=""  # your network's password
}
```

Comment: Before I got a chance to bypass NM the wifi began working as before.  I reset the wifi hub due to an issue with other devices.  So perhaps that was where the problem was.  Thanks for taking the time to propose a solution.