# Wireless Authentication Problem [20.04]

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, realtek-wireless, wpa-supplicant

## Wireless Authentication Problem on Ubuntu 20.04

### Issue Description:

I am unable to connect to any wireless network, so far I have tested 3 networks on both 5, and 2.4GHz bands. Every test I have noticed that the connection will stop during the authentication phase, as Ubuntu is able to find and search the networks no problem. Only when it comes to authentication, it has issues.

Every time I attempt to login via gnome and the network manager gui, it asks for a password, attempts to connect, and then asks for a password again without any error message in the GUI.

### Some information about my device:

- **OS**: Ubuntu 20.04 (installed yesterday)
- **Laptop**: ASUS TUF FX505D
- **Wireless Driver**: RTL8822CE
- **wpa_supplicant version**: v2.9

The drivers I have loaded for realtek are as follows (from `lsmod | grep rtw`)

```
rtwpci                 24576  0
rtw88                 610304  1 rtwpci
mac80211              843776  2 rtwpci,rtw88
cfg80211              704512  2 mac80211,rtw88
```

### Some things I have tried:

- Re-installed wpa_supplicant (`sudo apt reinstall wpasupplicant`)
- Tried 3 different networks (varing between 2.4GHz, and 5GHz)
- Attempted manual connection using wpa_supplicant (see below)

In order to get the log directly from wpa_supplicant, I used the [following script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053691/ubuntu-18-wifi-wont-authenticate) to attempt to authenticate to my wireless network (SSID and PASSWORD are replaced with the actual SSID and Password of the network).

```bsh
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
wpa_passphrase SSID PASSWORD > network.conf
sudo wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -iwlp4s0 -cnetwork.conf
```

From this, I get the following output:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlp4s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with f8:1d:0f:90:6f:c8 (SSID='SSID' freq=2462 MHz)
wlp4s0: Trying to associate with f8:1d:0f:90:6f:c8 (SSID='SSID' freq=2462 MHz)
wlp4s0: SME: Deauth request to the driver failed
wlp4s0: Associated with f8:1d:0f:90:6f:c8
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=f8:1d:0f:90:6f:c8 reason=2
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
wlp4s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with f8:1d:0f:90:6f:c8 (SSID='SSID' freq=2462 MHz)
wlp4s0: Trying to associate with f8:1d:0f:90:6f:c8 (SSID='SSID' freq=2462 MHz)
wlp4s0: SME: Deauth request to the driver failed
wlp4s0: Associated with f8:1d:0f:90:6f:c8
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=f8:1d:0f:90:6f:c8 reason=2
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="SSID" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="SSID"
wlp4s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with f8:1d:0f:90:6f:c8 (SSID='SSID' freq=2462 MHz)
wlp4s0: Trying to associate with f8:1d:0f:90:6f:c8 (SSID='SSID' freq=2462 MHz)
wlp4s0: SME: Deauth request to the driver failed
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="SSID" auth_failures=2 duration=23 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlp4s0: Associated with f8:1d:0f:90:6f:c8
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=f8:1d:0f:90:6f:c8 reason=2
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="SSID" auth_failures=3 duration=46 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="SSID"
wlp4s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with f8:1d:0f:90:6f:c8 (SSID='SSID' freq=2462 MHz)
wlp4s0: Trying to associate with f8:1d:0f:90:6f:c8 (SSID='SSID' freq=2462 MHz)
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=f8:1d:0f:90:6f:c8 reason=3 locally_generated=1
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp4s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
```

Other devices are able to connect to said wireless networks perfectly fine. This is a clean install of Ubuntu with very little on it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I have a Huawei Matebook 2020, also with the RTL8822CE chipset. I can only connect using `iwd`, but I'd prefer `wpa_supplicant` for better support for enterprise networks (automatic configuration of university networks). Possibly related: https://gitlab.tails.boum.org/tails/tails/-/issues/17865